# Product of columns selected by starts_with()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if there is an efficient way or alternative way to compute the row wise product of a selection of columns in dplyr format.
I know one way to do it (see below), but it seems using rowwise() take a long time to run on my large data set, hence looking for any alternative way to do this.

```
df = df %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate(myprod = prod(c_across(starts_with('var_xyz'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternative options.

If you want to stay in `tidyverse` you can try `pmap_dbl` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%  mutate(myprod = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with('var_xyz')), prod))
```

A base R option with `Reduce` or using  `rowProds` from `matrixStats`.

```
cols <- grep('^var_xyz', names(df))
#2.
df$myprod <- Reduce(`*`, df[cols])
#3.
df$myprod <- matrixStats::rowProds(as.matrix(df[cols]))
```